# How to link to apps on the app store for song download

Tags: ios7, itunes-store

I am creating music App in which I want to give the download song functionality. 
On download button click a alerts comes up which have buy song option,on buy song it will move to iTunes.

Comment: http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html ?

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: jus move to sign in iTunes Store pop up where it require Apple id And password.